# Excel VBA .find not find the value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I wanted to make a schedule macro and i tried to build in some random element too.

[image: Excel structure]

And in VBA i tried to `.Find()` the minimum value of Column "I" at first it worked, but when I expand the code to make is more useful for this case, suddenly its not find the value.

```
Sub schedule()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim days As Range, balance As Range
    Dim min As String
    Dim a As Range, i As Integer, o As Integer, Cell As Range

    Set ws = Application.Sheets("Teszt")
    Set days = ws.Range("L11:AP23")
    Set balance = ws.Range("I11:I23")

    
    For o = 1 To 31
        For i = 1 To 6
            'min = Format(WorksheetFunction.min(balance), "0.00")
            min = WorksheetFunction.min(balance)
            
                        'For Each Cell In balance
                        '    Debug.Print Cell.Value
                        'Next Cell
                        Debug.Print "----"
                
            Set a = balance.Find(what:=min, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                lookat:=xlWhole, _
                searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                searchdirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)
                
            a.Offset(0, o + 2).Value = "x"
            a.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
            
        Next i
        
        ws.Range("J11:J23").Value = ""
        
    Next o
End Sub
```

Now i don't find why the "Set a" part not working
Column "I" contains a formula G-H+J the result is a double and I search the lowest value from that range. For teszting purposes i only work with 11:23 Row

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question.

Comment: `Dim min As String` why??? it sould be something like `Dim min As Single` or `As Double`. `Find`. is searching for a text inside numbers.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns i left it like that because it worked that way previously. However, it's not working neither way now.

Answer (score 0):

Well.
It's not a "true" answer for this problem but it works anyway. So, I just leave it here to anyone who have similar problem:

Just don't use Double. Or Single. No floating point, no problem...
There are plenty of way to bring it up above zero and if it's just an integer it works fine.

I thought some other methods but any of it would take much more computing capacity than it's worth. Not to mention that working with integer is much faster. After I switched to it the code is at least two times faster.